# Continuum hypothesis and the cardinality of regular expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The regular expression **a*** matches symbol streams that look like *aaa...*, i.e. the set *{'','a','aa','aaa','aaaa',...}*.

The regular expression **[0-9]*** matches streams of digits. Since **[0-9]*** matches all positive integers, its cardinality is $\aleph_0$, i.e. countable infinity. The regular expression **[0-9]*.[0-9]*** matches all positive reals. Therefore, its cardinality is $\aleph_1$, i.e. uncountable infinity.

Is the cardinality of **[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*** equal to $\aleph_2$?

In general, is the cardinality of a digit stream with **k** decimal separators, i.e. cardinality of the regular expression **([0-9]*.)*{1,\$k}**, equal to $\aleph_k$?

Comment: Usually, I'd say that Kleene star does not admit infinitely long strings, so the cardinality of $[0-9]^*.[0-9]^*$ is countable.  Even if you permitted it to comprise infinitely long strings, the set of triples is not $\aleph_2$.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think the question is worth a downvote.

Comment: @BrianTung Oh, I see. You are right. A free monoid is defined as a finite sequence. Is there another, similar set comprehension system that allows for infinite sequences?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, ok, I would need a regular expression example (assuming that infinite were allowed) as a witness that would have a cardinality of $\aleph_2$ (merely assuming the continuum hypothesis, obviously), or can this system simply not possibly express a set comprehension that goes beyond the cardinality of the continuum? That would actually also be an interesting conclusion.

Comment: Even if this had the cardinality of the reals, that would be $2^{\aleph_0},$ not necessarily $\aleph_1.$ The continuum hypothesis is the statement that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1,$ which is not provable or refutable from ZFC. (Sorry, I deleted and rewrote this comment cause the last part of it was wrong.)

Comment: First off, note that if you let $[0-9]^*$ mean the set of all infinite sequences, then even the first one with no separators has cardinality of the continuum. And the ones with separators e.g. $[0-9]^*.[0-9]^*$ or $[0-9]^*.[0-9]^*.[0-9]^*$ all have cardinality of the continuum as well. $(2^{\aleph_0})^n= 2^{\aleph_0}$ for any $n\le \aleph_0,$ particularly any finite $n$.

Comment: Also, when you say "beyond" cardinality of the continuum this is a misconception. The continuum may well be much, much larger than $\aleph_2.$ In fact it's consistent that it is arbitrarily large with respect to the $\aleph_\alpha$ hierarchy.

Comment: The product of two infinite numbers equals the larger of the two.

Comment: I would be looking for a regular expression (with infinite strings allowed) that has a bijection with the power set of the set of real numbers. If it exists, could anybody construct a witness? If it does not exist, is the impossibility provable? Or is the question uberhaupt decidable? An argument claiming undecidability is also a good solution.

Comment: Wait, or are you assuming the CH? I don't know what "merely assuming the CH, obviously" means, (If so, there's really no reason to... you can just ask if there's a way to construct something with size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ this way. It seems like the CH is irrelevant here.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, if a correspondence could be established between (infinity) regular expressions and $\aleph$ cardinalities, it may actually create additional structure that could possibly impact the continuum hypothesis ... ?

Comment: You can't "impact the continuum hypothesis" except by adding new axioms to ZFC. It's hard to say if it's possible to represent a set of size of power set of reals with expressions like this cause you haven't given a precise definition. My guess is 'no' assuming you aren't going to relax more assumptions. If it can be expressed in terms of finitely or even countably many $\omega$-sequences of digits, it can only represent continuum-many things.

Comment: Your "regular expressions with infinite strings allowed" just seems to be
$$\left|10^\omega \cup \bigcup_{k\in \omega} 10^k\right| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$$
You can't really do much more with it, since, as William Elliot mentioned, no finite number of separators can change this value.

Comment: As a sidenote, to understand the limitations of ZFC in regard to the decidability of CH, it may be useful to think about why the axiom of infinity is required as an axiom in ZF.  Specifically, if you had ZF minus the axiom of infinity, then there would be no way to prove whether infinite sets exist or not within that limited framework.  Do infinite sets _actually_ exist?  Who knows, but it's useful to assume they do.

Comment: @Brian Moehring, ok. Point taken. Sets of symbol streams of which the cardinality exceeds that one of the continuum, may indeed not even be possible ...

Comment: I think these regular expressions match finite things. The set of finite strings of  digits from 0 to 9 is countable. If you have an infinite expression, then your computer never stops reading, and never gives you an answer. Also, do you mean cardinality of a regular expression, or of the set of things it matches, and did you ever define what if your interpretation of the set of things that  [0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]* matches? I do not understand how [0-9]*.[0-9]* matches all positive reals, to me at best it matches some (not all) rational numbers, if you interpret that separator as a decimal point.